# What I want is to get all the transactions at once if the sms permission is provided for the first time

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, sms, android-permissions, android-jetpack

SMS PERMISSION HANDLER

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
@Composable
fun SMSPermissionHandling(
    mainNavController: NavHostController
) {
    val permissionState = rememberPermissionState(permission = Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val sharedPreferences =
        LocalContext.current.getSharedPreferences("MySharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val permissionGrantedToastShown =
        sharedPreferences.getBoolean("permissionGrantedToastShown", false)
    val permissionDialogCanceled = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("permissionDialogCanceled", false)

    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current

    DisposableEffect(key1 = lifecycleOwner, effect = {
        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
            when (event) {
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_START -> {
                    if (!permissionState.hasPermission && !permissionState.shouldShowRationale && !permissionState.permissionRequested && !permissionDialogCanceled) {
                        permissionState.launchPermissionRequest()
                    }
                }
                else -> {
                    if (permissionDialogCanceled) {
                        mainNavController.navigate(Main.route)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)

        onDispose {
            lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    })

    LaunchedEffect(permissionState.hasPermission, permissionState.shouldShowRationale) {
        if (permissionState.hasPermission) {
            if (!permissionGrantedToastShown) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "SMS permission has been granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show()
                sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("permissionGrantedToastShown", true).apply()
            }
            mainNavController.navigate(Main.route)
        } else if (!permissionState.shouldShowRationale && permissionState.permissionRequested) {
            mainNavController.navigate(Main.route)
        }
    }


    LaunchedEffect(permissionState.permissionRequested) {
        if (permissionState.permissionRequested && !permissionState.hasPermission && !permissionState.shouldShowRationale) {
            coroutineScope.launch {
                mainNavController.navigate(Main.route)
            }
        }
    }

    when {
        permissionState.shouldShowRationale && !permissionDialogCanceled -> {
            // Show rationale in an AlertDialog
            AlertDialog(
                onDismissRequest = {
                    // do nothing
                },
                title = {
                    Text(text = "Permission Required")
                },
                text = {
                    Text(
                        text = "Granting SMS permission is optional but enables automated expense tracking."
                    )
                },
                confirmButton = {
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End
                    ) {
                        Button(
                            onClick = {
                                // Request the permission again
                                coroutineScope.launch {
                                    permissionState.launchPermissionRequest()
                                }
                            },
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 4.dp)
                        ) {
                            Text(text = "Request Permission")
                        }
                        Button(
                            onClick = {
                                // Navigate to the main screen when dismissed
                                sharedPreferences.edit()
                                    .putBoolean("permissionDialogCanceled", true).apply()
                                mainNavController.navigate(Main.route)
                            },
                            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = Color.Red)
                        ) {
                            Text(text = "Cancel")
                        }
                    }
                },
                dismissButton = null
            )
        }
    }
}
```

This is where we are getting sms from

```
class TransactionSMSReader(private val contentResolver: ContentResolver) {

    private val smsFilter = TransactionSMSFilter()

    private companion object {
        const val ID_COLUMN = "_id"
        const val ADDRESS_COLUMN = "address"
        const val BODY_COLUMN = "body"
        const val PERSON_COLUMN = "person"
        const val DATE_COLUMN = "date"
    }

    private fun readTransactionSMS(cursor: Cursor): SMSMessageDTO? {
        val address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ADDRESS_COLUMN))
        val body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BODY_COLUMN))
        val time = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DATE_COLUMN))

        val amountSpent = smsFilter.getAmountSpent(body)
        val isExpense = smsFilter.isExpense(body)
        val isIncome = smsFilter.isIncome(body)

        return if (amountSpent != null && (isExpense || isIncome)) {
            SMSMessageDTO(address, body, time)
        } else {
            null
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun getFormattedDate(timeStamp: Long): String {
        val localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(timeStamp), ZoneId.systemDefault())
        return localDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault()))
    }

    private fun queryTransactionMessages(from: Long?, to: Long?): List<SMSMessageDTO> {
        val transactionMessages = mutableListOf<SMSMessageDTO>()

        val projections = arrayOf(ID_COLUMN, ADDRESS_COLUMN, BODY_COLUMN, PERSON_COLUMN, DATE_COLUMN)
        val selection = if (from != null && to != null) "$DATE_COLUMN >= ? AND $DATE_COLUMN <= ?" else null
        val selectionArgs = if (from != null && to != null) arrayOf(from.toString(), to.toString()) else null
        val sortOrder = "$DATE_COLUMN DESC"

        contentResolver.query(
            Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),
            projections,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            sortOrder
        )?.use { cursor ->
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                readTransactionSMS(cursor)?.let { transactionMessages.add(it) }
            }
        }

        return transactionMessages
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    fun getTransactionSMS(startMillis:Long, endMillis: Long): Map<String, List<SMSMessageDTO>> {
        val allSMSMessages = queryTransactionMessages(startMillis, endMillis)

        return allSMSMessages.groupBy { sms -> getFormattedDate(sms.time) }
    }
}
```

This is the repo for now

```
class TransactionRepositoryImpl(
    private val transactionDao: TransactionDao,
    private val accountDao: AccountDao,
    private val transactionSMSReader: TransactionSMSReader,
    private val smsBoundResource: SMSBoundResource
) : TransactionRepository {
    private val smsFilter = TransactionSMSFilter()
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override suspend fun getAllTransactions(from: Long, to: Long): Flow<Resource<List<Transaction>>> {
        return smsBoundResource.bind(
            query = {
                transactionDao.getTransactions(from, to)
            },
            fetch = {
                transactionSMSReader.getTransactionSMS(from, to).values.flatten()
            },
            saveFetchResult = {smsMessageList->
                val transactions = mutableListOf<Transaction>()
                smsMessageList.forEach { message ->
                    val amount = smsFilter.getAmountSpent(message.body) ?: 0.0
                    val type = if (smsFilter.isExpense(message.body)) "Expense" else "Income"
                    val accountId = smsFilter.extractAccount(message.body)?.lowercase()
                        ?.replaceFirstChar {
                            if (it.isLowerCase()) it.titlecase(
                                Locale.getDefault()
                            ) else it.toString()
                        } ?: "N/A"
                    var account: Account? = null
                    if(accountId!="N/A"){
                        account = accountId.let { it1 -> accountDao.getAccount(it1) }
                    }
                    val categoryName = account?.defaultCategory ?:TransactionCategories.UNKNOWN
                    val otherPartyName = account?.accountName ?: accountId
                    val title = "What For?"

                    transactions.add(
                        Transaction(
                            timestamp = message.time,
                            title = title,
                            otherPartyName = otherPartyName,
                            amount = amount,
                            type = type,
                            categoryName = categoryName,
                            accountId = accountId
                        )
                    )
                }
                transactionDao.insertAllTransactions(transactions)
            }
        )
    }

    override suspend fun updateTransaction(transaction: Transaction) {
        try {
            transactionDao.updateTransaction(transaction)
        } catch (e: SQLiteConstraintException) {
            // Handle the exception (e.g., log the error, show a message)
        }
    }


    override suspend fun updateTransactionsOfId(accountId: String, categoryName: String, otherPartyName: String) {
        try {
            val transactionsToUpdate = transactionDao.getTransactionsByAccountId(accountId)
            val updatedTransactions = transactionsToUpdate.map { transaction ->
                transaction.copy(
                    categoryName = categoryName,
                    otherPartyName = otherPartyName
                )
            }
            transactionDao.updateTransactionsOfId(updatedTransactions)
        } catch (e: SQLiteConstraintException) {
            // Handle the exception (e.g., log the error, show a message)
        }
    }



    override fun getCategoryTransactions(category: String): Resource<List<Transaction>> {
        return try {
            Resource.Success(transactionDao.getTransactionsByCategory(category))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Resource.Error(e, emptyList())
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is that when and if the sms permission is granted for the first time the app should read all the messages there itself and identify the transaction messages using the filter that has been implemented.

[Github](https://github.com/GoelYash1/Expense-Tracker-2.0): Here is the code link if anyone is interested to look at it

Thanks in advance.

I have not tried much but would be grateful for your help.